# MongoDB - how do I pull the record based on the first element in array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, filter, element, projection

Here are 2 documents in the attached file. I need to pull the title field based on the filter (Harrison Ford is the 1st element in the actor field). So I need to pull the 2nd document. Thanks for your help.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e66e96a2f86fd04deaa59c5"),
        "title" : "Star Trek Into Darkness",
        "actors" : [
                "Chris Pine",
                "Zachary Quinto",
                "Harrison Ford",
                "Karl Urban"
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e66e96a2f86fd04deaa59c6"),
        "title" : "Raiders of the lost ark",
        "actors" : [
                "Harrison Ford",
                "Jonathan Frakes",
                "Brent Spiner",
                "LeVar Burton"
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

so you want to get the title of a movie that has `Harrison Ford` as the first actor right?
if so, give this a try:

```
db.collection.find(
    { 'actors.0': 'Harrison Ford' },
    { title: 1, _id: 0 }
)
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/f4-o13NjYNc

btw, when you say `pull` it may confuse people because there's a `$pull` operator in mongodb.

Comment: That worked, Thank you for quick response. I was playing around earlier with match, elemMatch , projection, but it did not work,

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.update({_id:'Your match id'}, {$pull:{actors:'Jonathan Frakes'}});

you can pull record with $pull and then update that record. Please check below link
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

Comment: Sorry i should not have used pull in my question. I was simply trying to extract. Its working not thanks for your reply.

Comment: you said that you want pull that record. @usal2100